# On odd Fourier coefficients of (elliptic) modular forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, galois-representations

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be any elliptic curve with no non-trivial $2$ torsion, and $\rho_E:\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})\to \mathrm{Aut}(E[2])=\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\cong S_3$ be the associated Galois representation. Assume that $\rho_E$ is surjective. Is there an way to classify the splitting structure of the primes $p$ ($p$ is any prime of good reduction) in $\mathbb{Q}(E[2])$ for which $\rho_{E}(\mathrm{Frob}_p)$ is a $3$-cycle? According to the proof of Proposition 3.4 in [https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~mkazal/reprints/supersingular.pdf](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/%7Emkazal/reprints/supersingular.pdf), if $p$ does not split completely in $\mathbb{Q}(E[2])$, then $\rho_E(\mathrm{Frob}_p)$ is a $3$-cycle. However, splitting completely corresponds to the identity in $S_3$, so what about the order $2$ elements?

Comment: $a_p$ is even if and only if it is the identity or a $2$-cycle. But the knowledge of $a_p$ alone will not be enough to determine which of the two cases it is. However in this case, the question is equivalent to whether the explicit polynomial $x^3+Ax+B$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Chebotarev tells you this happens in density 1/6 vs 1/3 of all primes. I don't know what to say more as I am not sure what answer you are hoping for.